# Display HTML widget programmatically anywhere wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have created three HMTL widgets in WordPress, I assign them footer area. Now I want to display them in footer with this code `<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text', 'title=Latest Tours' ); ?>` .`Latest Tour` is the widget title. But it shows only title no inner data. What am I missing?

My footer code is like this:

```
<div class="col_1">
                    <h2>Other Links</h2>
                    <?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text', 'title=Latest Tours' ); ?> 
</div>
```

function.php code:

```
function presscore_widgets_init() {

        if ( function_exists('of_get_option') ) {

            $w_params = array(
                'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget'  => '</section>',
                'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title">',
                'after_title'   => '</div>'
            );

            $w_areas = apply_filters( 'presscore_widgets_init-sidebars', of_get_option( 'widgetareas', false ) );

            if ( !empty( $w_areas ) && is_array( $w_areas ) ) {

                $prefix = 'sidebar_';

                foreach( $w_areas as $sidebar_id=>$sidebar ) {

                    $sidebar_args = array(
                        'name'          => isset( $sidebar['sidebar_name'] ) ? $sidebar['sidebar_name'] : '',
                        'id'            => $prefix . $sidebar_id,
                        'description'   => isset( $sidebar['sidebar_desc'] ) ? $sidebar['sidebar_desc'] : '',
                        'before_widget' => $w_params['before_widget'],
                        'after_widget'  => $w_params['after_widget'],
                        'before_title'  => $w_params['before_title'],
                        'after_title'   => $w_params['after_title'] 
                    );

                    $sidebar_args = apply_filters( 'presscore_widgets_init-sidebar_args', $sidebar_args, $sidebar_id, $sidebar );

                    register_sidebar( $sidebar_args );
                }
            }
        }
    }

endif; // presscore_widgets_init

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'presscore_widgets_init' );
```

OUPUT:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [sidebar_name] =&gt; Default Sidebar
            [sidebar_desc] =&gt; Sidebar primary widget area
        )

    [2] =&gt; Array
        (
            [sidebar_name] =&gt; Default Footer
            [sidebar_desc] =&gt; Footer primary widget area
        )

)
</pre>
```

Comment: So you have created three text widgets in the admin (Appearance -> Widgets) and put them in an area titled "Footer Area", correct?

Comment: @NathanDawson yes you are right.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your footer.php file? Is this based on an existing theme? If so which one? If not can you include the code you used to add the widget area (register_sidebar())?

Comment: I have add the footer code.there is nothing special on footer just dummy text.I am using 7 theme.i don't know that either this is ready made or someone created .

Comment: OK you need to find the register_sidebar code for the footer area. Do a search inside functions.php and paste here if you find it. Without that I can only guess as to the code you need to use.

Comment: i only find this function `function presscore_widgets_init()` which contain register_sidebar ? are you talking about this

Comment: yes, please paste that code into your original question

Comment: check now the question

Comment: OK we need to work out the name of the sidebar. Can you add the following code to your footer and then paste the output here? <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r( apply_filters( 'presscore_widgets_init-sidebars', of_get_option( 'widgetareas', false ) ) ); echo '</pre>'; ?>

Comment: wow it shows me arrays with first one for sidebar and second contains my html widget.Now please post you code in answer area so that i can accept it.And also how can i directly get my results ?

Comment: I'm pleased that helped. Please paste the output into your original question and I'll package it up for you into a single line of code to use. In particular we're looking for the 'name' of each sidebar

Comment: I pasted the code .it works only if contest are simple text but for links it didn't work.like `<ul><li>` etc

Comment: The code I gave you was to obtain some information I needed to help solve your question rather than the final code. I have now added an answer. Please test and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your footer.php file:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_2' ); ?>
```

Comment: one last question.what code for 3 and 4 ? `sidebar_3` ?

Comment: Can you clarify? The footer area you put the widgets in (in the WordPress admin) has the ID of 'sidebar_2'. By using the code I provided any widgets in the "Default Footer" widget area will be shown. So if you put 3 widgets into that area then using the code will show the three widgets. If you created a new widget area then yes, you would use sidebar_3. The sidebars increment according to the code I've seen.